# Changing the home folder for ftp user in windows server 2008 R2

Tags: ftp

I created ftp account through DotNetPanel and for some reason now it throws eror "hexadecimal value 0x03, is an invalid character.". However I noticed that an user has been created on the server and I am able to login through ftp client.

When I am logging in, it points to C:\inetpub\ftproot folder. Now I want to change the pointing folder so that I can point this user to my website folder and I can upload the files for my website.

Any help please.

Answer (score 2):

I realize you ask about user directories and my below answer was how to change the default  home directory for your FTP site. Since you may still want to do that I have included it at the end of my answer.

Here is how to change the Users folder location:

Open the FTP User Isolation icon from inside the IIS website that houses your FTP and make the changes as necessary such as `Isolate Users: User Name Directory`

[image]

[image]

To Change the Default Home directory of FTP: First right click on the site you have FTP set up for and Choose Advanced Settings

[image]

Then change the `PhysicalPath` to one you want:
[image]